# MapStruct - @Mapper annotation don't create bean

Tags: spring, mapper, mapstruct

I downloaded application from this source https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring5-mvc-rest/tree/vendor-api
And I have a problem with MapStruct.

```
@Mapper
public interface CategoryMapper {

CategoryMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CategoryMapper.class);


CategoryDTO categoryToCategoryDTO(Category category);
```

}

```
@Data
public class CategoryDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

domain class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    private final CategoryMapper categoryMapper;
    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public CategoryServiceImpl(CategoryMapper categoryMapper, CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.categoryMapper = categoryMapper;
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }
}
```

And in pom.xml dependency, I paste only two::

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.CR2</org.mapstruct.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                 <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                 <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                 <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                 <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                 <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                 <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
           </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
           <compilerArg>
                 -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
           </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Description:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in 
guru.springfamework.services.CategoryServiceImpl required a bean of type 'guru.springfamework.api.v1.mapper.CategoryMapper' that could not be found.
```

Action:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'guru.springfamework.api.v1.mapper.CategoryMapper' in your configuration.
```

I think that in my Intellij annotation @Mapper don't create a bean for mapper.
I didn't change code from John GitHub.
Any idea?
I tried to change path generated source to target but this doesn't help
Thanks for help.

Comment: Check if you have annotiation process enabled in intellij preferences

Comment: Yes. It's enabled.

Comment: That's strange, I compiled & run the example branch mapstruct and everything seems to be working. Maybe try to update intellij version or install mapstruct plugin for intellij

Comment: Can you try to run vendor-api branch? Because mapstruct branch hasn't dependency injection and don't use mapper.

Comment: Is the problem only in IntelliJ or also running maven from the command line?

Comment: Thank you for some tips. I checked this app in maven and there was error, that maven plugin cannot be resolved. I found tip that i have to set JAVA_HOME env variable. I forgot about this variable after reinstall my widnows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Mapper class, use `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` instead of just `@Mapper`

and `run mvn clean install`, that's it! you're done!

and the **alternative** to it, is to define compiler arguments in plugin of **pom.xml** like below!

```
 <plugin>
     <configuration>
         <compilerArgs>
             <compilerArg>
                 -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
             </compilerArg>
         </compilerArgs>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: @AdrianElder that's what I've mentioned in the answer itself! both the things are alternatives of each other!

Comment: For those using Gradle, the equivalent commands are `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` followed by a `./gradlew clean build`.

Answer (score 43):

I resolved the error by doing

1. mvn clean install
2. Also add this to your pom

   ```
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.7.0</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
               <annotationProcessorPaths>
                   <path>
                       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                       <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                   </path>
                   <path>
                       <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                       <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                       <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                   </path>
               </annotationProcessorPaths>
               <compilerArgs>
                   <compilerArg>
                          -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                   </compilerArg>
               </compilerArgs>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```

Comment: Only with: <version>3.7.0</version> idea started to use <compilerArg> for me.

Comment: Thanks, I struggled with this for days!
Apparently we have to execute mvn clean install or mvn clean verify to trigger MapStruct processing, which will generate the implementation class under /target/generated-sources/annotations/.

Comment: Adding mapstruct-processor fixed it for me, Thanks.

Comment: For those using Gradle, the equivalent commands are `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` followed by a `./gradlew clean build`.

Answer (score 13):

The issue is that using the `@Mapper` construct will generate a class *without*
the @Component annotation by default.

You are probably not using Maven to compile your project. Make sure to run a Maven `clean` and `install`, or pass in the compiler arguments `mapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring` manually.

Since you are using:

```
    <compilerArgs>
       <compilerArg>
             -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
       </compilerArg>
    </compilerArgs>
```

This will tell `MapStruct` to generate a `Spring Component`.

If you check your compiled target class, and open it up in a decompiler (if your IDE supports this), there should be a `CategoryMapperImpl` that is annotated with @Component.

Answer (score 12):

In order to use mappers as beans and use `@Autowired`, just declare mappers as `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`. Then just inject it wherever you need this.

Comment: I don't think @Autowired is required because in the problem, constructor dependency injection is used.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. In Gradle I solved it by adding new dependency:

```
compileOnly('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Beta2')
```

And all necessary dependencies should be as follows:

```
compile('org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Beta2')
compileOnly('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Beta2')
annotationProcessor('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Beta2')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Added these both dependencies solved my problem, processor needed for creating beans (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-processor), if the red line on the constructor bothers you (it does not bother compiler) `@Autowired(required = false)` add this.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when I added the annotationProcessor for both dependencies.

```
annotationProcessor group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct', version: '1.4.2.Final'
implementation group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct', version: '1.4.2.Final'
annotationProcessor group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-processor', version: '1.4.2.Final'
implementation group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-processor', version: '1.4.2.Final'
```

Also, made sure using

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the missing `componentModel` in the `@Mapper` annotation on the interface / abstract class.
So this didn't work:

`@Mapper`

But this worked:

`@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`

Comment: It also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by first installing MAVEN_HOME in environment variables then do a **mvn clean install**. I've found out that I was running my project in eclipse and then Intellij without installing maven.

Comment: For those using Gradle, the equivalent commands are `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` followed by a `./gradlew clean build`.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that this is not working in IntelliJ only. There is a known issue, where IntelliJ actually does not pick up the annotation processors from the maven compiler `annotationProcessorPaths` (see [IDEA-150621](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150621) for more info).

On top of that the examples in the linked repository are against MapStruct best practices. When the `spring` `componentModel` is used then `Mappers.getMapper` should never be used. The reason is that the factory will not be able to construct the mapper correctly as it should be constructed via spring. Also the compiler argument `mapstruct.defaultComponentModel` can break integration with IDE, as it is not being picked up (you would need to set it in the IntelliJ settings as well)

Answer (score 1):

This was working for me:

1. POM Dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. POM Plugins:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

3. Having `componentModel = "spring"` parameter in `@MapStruct` annotation.
4. Run `mvn clean` on your project.

I don't think you really need the following compiler argument declaration in your POM, because ``componentModel = "spring"` should be enough.

```xml
<plugin>
     <configuration>
         <compilerArgs>
             <compilerArg>
                 -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
             </compilerArg>
         </compilerArgs>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've taken these code snippets from a microservice application project generated by [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/).

Answer (score 1):

Use this annotation on the mapper class and do not add a plugin as this annotation will create a bean.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining why

Comment: the componentModel = "spring" attribute tells MapStruct to generate a Spring-managed bean for the Mapper interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable your annotation processor in you IntelliJ from,

> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation
>   Processors and click on checkbox of Enable annotation processing.

Comment: As well you need to uncheck IntelliJ Run Configuration's "Enable lunch optimization"

Answer (score 0):

You first have to use the Mapper like this

```
To use mappers as beans and use **@Autowired**,
just declare mappers as @Mapper(componentModel = "spring"). 
Then just inject it wherever you need this.
```

Also every time you create a new mapper class always remember to do **mvn clean install**.

It will create the implementation file of you mapper interface in the target folder and then you can run your Spring project.

Comment: For those using Gradle, the equivalent commands are `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` followed by a `./gradlew clean build`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, add in your mapper class.
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
So,
Instead of @Mapper add @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")

Answer (score 0):

@ComponentScan("guru.springfamework.api.v1.mapper")

Add this under a config class or MainClass