# Spring Boot doesn't find my Java bean mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, mapstruct

I'm getting an error when I try to start Spring Boot using a Java bean mapper. I'm using Eclipse on Windows, Gradle to build. This is just a learning project I'm using to learn these components.

I'm listening to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue, using the incoming data to call a web service, then saving the order response in a MondoDB. All the components are working with the exception of the mapper converting the api response to a MongoDB entity.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? It's something with how I'm injecting the OrderMapper, but I'm not sure at this point. This is the Spring output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)

2021-04-30 14:16:15.860  INFO 2320 --- [           main] c.b.R.RestClientPocApplication           : Starting RestClientPocApplication using Java 11.0.9 on PSPLT-F7VYYY2 with PID 2320 (C:\Users\Bwarrick\Workspaces\Java\RESTClientPOC\bin\main started by Bwarrick in C:\Users\Bwarrick\Workspaces\Java\RESTClientPOC)
2021-04-30 14:16:15.863  INFO 2320 --- [           main] c.b.R.RestClientPocApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-30 14:16:16.405  INFO 2320 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-30 14:16:16.567  INFO 2320 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 157 ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-04-30 14:16:16.991  INFO 2320 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.56.102:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-04-30 14:16:17.064  INFO 2320 --- [68.56.102:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:49}] to 192.168.56.102:27017
2021-04-30 14:16:17.064  INFO 2320 --- [68.56.102:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:50}] to 192.168.56.102:27017
2021-04-30 14:16:17.065  INFO 2320 --- [68.56.102:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=192.168.56.102:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=23420200}
2021-04-30 14:16:17.332  WARN 2320 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artemisConsumer' defined in file [C:\Users\Bwarrick\Workspaces\Java\RESTClientPOC\bin\main\com\benwarrick\RESTClientPOC\jms\ArtemisConsumer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.OrderMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2021-04-30 14:16:17.355  INFO 2320 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-04-30 14:16:17.370 ERROR 2320 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.jms.ArtemisConsumer required a bean of type 'com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.OrderMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.OrderMapper' in your configuration.
```

Here is my component:

```
package com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.jms;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.persistance.OrderEntity;
    import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.persistance.OrderRepository;
    import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.CoinBaseClientServiceImpl;
    import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.OrderMapper;
    import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.OrderResponse;
    import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.Price;
    import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service.Prices;
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
    import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
    
    @Component
    public class ArtemisConsumer {
    
        private final OrderRepository orderRepository; 
        private final OrderMapper orderMapper;
        
        @Autowired
        public ArtemisConsumer(OrderRepository orderRepository, OrderMapper orderMapper) {
            this.orderRepository = orderRepository; 
            this.orderMapper = orderMapper; 
        }
        
        
        @JmsListener(destination = "test.topic::test.queue")
        public void receive(String msg){
            System.out.println("Got Message: " + msg);
            
            CoinBaseClientServiceImpl client = new CoinBaseClientServiceImpl();
            
            Mono<OrderResponse>orderCreate = client.createOrder("market", "USD", "BTC", "5");
            orderCreate.log().subscribe(
                    successValue -> processResponse(successValue),
                    error -> System.err.println(error.getMessage()),
                    () -> System.out.println("mono consumed")
                    );
        }
        
        public void processResponse(OrderResponse orderResponse) {
            
            System.out.println(orderResponse.getOrderID() + " " + orderResponse.getSellingCurrency() + orderResponse.getBuyingCurrency() + " Qty: " 
                    + orderResponse.getBoughtQty() + " Type: " + orderResponse.getOrderType()) ;
            try {
            OrderEntity entity = orderMapper.apiResponseToEntity(orderResponse); 
            OrderEntity newEntity = orderRepository.save(entity); 
            System.out.println("Test: " + newEntity.getBoughtQuantity()); 
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString()) ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my main process:

```
package com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class RestClientPocApplication {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestClientPocApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = 
        SpringApplication.run(RestClientPocApplication.class, args);
        String mongoDBHost = ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.host");
        String mongoDbPort = ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.port");
        LOG.info("Connected to MongoDb: " + mongoDBHost + ":" + mongoDbPort); 
    }

}
```

And here is the bean that isn't being found:

```
package com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.service;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.Mappings;

import com.benwarrick.RESTClientPOC.persistance.OrderEntity;

@Mapper (componentModel = "spring")
public interface OrderMapper {
    
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "version", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "orderId", source="orderID"),
        @Mapping(target = "orderID", source="boughtQty")
    })
    OrderEntity apiResponseToEntity(OrderResponse api); 
}
```

And my build.graddle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.benwarrick'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    mapstructVersion = "1.4.2.Final"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstructVersion}")
    compileOnly "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    testImplementation('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109827/mapstruct-mapper-annotation-dont-create-bean can this be helpful?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that one. I have the dependencies correct in the build.gradle file (I think) as far as that post goes. I've using this example as my main guide: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Microservices-with-Spring-Boot-and-Spring-Cloud/blob/master/Chapter06/microservices/product-service/build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MapStruct you need to correctly set up annotation processor so that IDE (Eclipse in your case) and build tool, Gradle that is play well together.

You can read on [MapStruct page uder IDE support](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/) about it. Now I didn't manage to get it working without issues that way.

Plugin to the rescue! Now what I recommend you is that you use following Gradle plugin that can set up Eclipse IDE in a proper way for you. The plugin: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.diffplug.eclipse.apt

I see you know already how to include the plugin, just in case the code that you have to add to build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.diffplug.eclipse.apt' version "3.29.1"
}
```

And then run the command from your project that will set up Eclipse:

```
./gradlew eclipseJdtApt eclipseFactorypath eclipseJdt
```

From within Eclipse, you now have to run right-click the project and select Gradle / Refresh Gradle Project.

[image]

Afterwards, Project / Clean. With this clean build, the annotation-processor should be running.

I hope Eclipse Buildship will pick this up and make it easier to support his feature.